# How do I handle rare characters with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm accepting users to enter text into a textarea, and then save it (it's saved into a simple .txt file, and also contains html). Then the text file is grabbed using file_get_contents() and then echoed. This works fine, except when I test it with rare characters. For example, when I test it with, say, a clover (♧), it saves it just fine to the text file, but when I display it, it's something like â˜€. Almost all the rare symbols are prefixed with â. I'm guessing this is some encoding issue but I don't know where to begin. More specifically, how can I make sure anything any user inputs can end up being displayed correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Use UTF-8 encoding on your page.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**how can I make sure anything any user inputs can end up being displayed correctly?**`

Only accept UTF-8 encoded strings

PHP comes with a convenient function called [mb_check_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) — Check if the string is valid for the specified encoding
Use this function to check if the the user input is not anything 'rare'

```
   if(mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8'))
   {
       // do stuff, input is UTF-8
   }
   else 
   {
        // input is not UTF-8
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

header content type defined in php

```
 header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

http://hiox.org/33451-non-standard-characters-handle-in-php.php

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the special characters to HTML entites, just before you echo it:

```
htmlentities($mytext);
```

Then the browser will convert them back into the correct characters at the other end. There are two small disadvantages:

1. HTML entities take up a few bytes of extra space
2. If you are saving to a text file, then the HTML entities will not be converted back to the correct characters.

It may not be ideal, but it should do the job.